Can copper-based blood be efficient in a rich oxygen alien world?
I’m trying to figure out how to make the creatures in my world more efficient. It's a cold and rich oxygen planet.
I think hemocyanin could be an interesting choice since it's efficient in cold environments, but it's more suited for low-oxygen conditions.
Is there any modification I could make or perhaps another protein that could fit better into my world?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I see these questions from time to time and want to give some advice. Accuracy & realism are great details in a book, but they aren't the core if the book. It is more important to have a good story and characters. We're also talking about hypothetical aliens that the general population wouldn't know the realism of. To them it is fiction. Not to mention we haven't found aliens yet, so they'rev fiction like that as well. That is why it is doubly important to check if you even need to justify more efficient organisms. Such realism details are more likely to constrain than to actually aid a story.

(a) I removed the [tag:worldbuilding-process] tag because you're not asking a question about the process of worldbuilding. (b) I can't upvote @Trioxidane's comment enough. (c) Yours might be a duplicate of this question.  Please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand our goals and limitations. Thanks.

@JBH -- Would this query meet the Rule of Cool rule?

@elemtilas I think it would. To be frank, how many readers in the world would know enough about cardiovascular biology to even know if any use of the idea was within the bounds of known science? If asked, "what alternative blood bases could I use on an oxygen-rich imaginary world?" the answer "copper-based" would be well within the space of suspension of disbelief. Morpheus, if you're interested in what we're talking about, look here.

I didn’t know about the Rule of Cool, so I’ll definitely look into it more. And the Spock reference is honestly pretty good — it really does offer a fresh perspective.
Thank you all for taking the time to provide such thoughtful responses and advice.

@Morpheus --- Greetings! Rule of Cool is actually a brand spanking new forum policy! Your question seemed to me a good one to use as a test bed. You may get other answers. You may even get better answers than mine!  All this really is is a way for the community of fellow worldbuilders to say "what you've got is good and perfect is often the enemy of good". Doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't pursue your research further; only that you have enough to go on!

@elemtilas Well... not quite yet. It needs its 10 votes (a very new standard, but we really need to get more votes than the half-dozen of us who frequent Meta). I'm especially appreciative of the [tag:worldbuilding-process] references you made in your answer. We need to incorporate that into the Rule of Cool reasoning. It's not just a way to quickly dispense with questions, there needs to be a worldbuilding (or at least professional story writing) justification.

On Earth hemoglobins, hemocyanins and hemerythrins are known to be used to transport oxygen. All three are classes of proteins rather than specific substances. But that is just what we have found so far on Earth.
On an alien world based on a completely different abiogenesis event almost anything might evolve depending on chance and the exact conditions. The number of permutations possible in chemistry exceeds the number of particles in the known universe by a huge margin.

Rule of Cool is in effect

Surely out of all the non-human sophont characters that have graced the pages and screens of SciFi works over the last 2000 years, Mr Spock is probably one of the most beloved. Standing across the gap of two different worlds, Earth and Vulcan, he presents us with a creature that is at once familiar and also quite alien.

And his blood is green. Okay, not quite blue, but the copper based hemocyanin is canonically the same as where you're heading in your world. Vulcan is arid and has a thinner atmosphere. Perhaps less oxygen?

And this is cool. It's different. It's based on science without being enslaved to science. This is the key element that I'd like to focus on. Here, we are not saying that details are bad or that realism is bad; but we are asking you to consider where and when to draw the line between enough and too much!

When the Rule of Cool is invoked, we are immediately put in mind of its meaning: "The limit of a group's willing suspension of disbelief for any given element in a story is directly proportional to its awesomeness". In this case, we the readers / gamers / viewers / etc of your world and any stories you write set therein are already accepting the existence of the world you're describing. A cold, oxygen rich world where there are people, non-human sophonts, in residence. We are already primed to suspend disbelief. We don't really need your help to suspend it any more, simply because we think green blood is cool!

You really don't need to get into alternate biochemistry in order to justify this element of your world. You simply tell us what your world is like and we'll believe you! In fact, overjustification can become detrimental to story telling simply because you are robbing your audience of our ability to exercise our own imagination. To bring this back to Star Trek, when we first met Spock, we didn't know a lot about Vulcan or its natural history. We didn't have to. We knew only that blood is green and that copper is involved. We didn't need to get into anything more specific than that.

I would argue that good worldbuilding should always increase the wonder, should allow sufficient mystery that imagination is engaged. Because this is where the artist, the work of art, and the art consumer (us) meet. This critical triple point of engagement.

Given that you've already admitted that green blood is unlikely or ill suited to your world as described, our usual line of response would probably include something like "Well, you said it yourself, worldbuilder! You have two things that don't work together, so you should change one or change the other!" Rule of Cool sets aside this more rigid purely scientific way of thinking and reapproaches the fictional world from a different perspective.

Your world is what it is and its people's blood is what it is --- and that's cool! You don't need to go into a detailed justification that would satisfy a biochemist or physiologist or an exohaematologist. I would therefore suggest taking a look at Graham's answer to the query JBH linked you to, for I think it provides you with good guidance: just as there are red blooded whales that can dive super deep, so too in your world there are green blooded people who do just fine up on the surface. Rather than just a simple query of "can this happen", you might then consider other, deeper questions of worldbuilding like "what can this do" and "what implications would this have".

NB: I think this is the first Rule of Cool answer for this forum. It may be a little rough around the edges, but I hope it gets the point across!
For those unaware, Rule of Cool answers are a little like Frame Challenges: they specifically don't answer the question as asked but rather challenge the querent to look at her own question with new eyes, a different perspective.

Be still my beating heart. But flattery aside - great answer and the Spock reference is perfect.

@TheDemonLord Please read my comment, above about including worldbuilding/storybuilding justification in the Rule of Cool. Thanks.

As Elementilas has said, alternate blood chemistry is cool.  As long as the stuff you propose can carry oxygen (and that oxygen is what your creatures need), it doesn't really matter if it's less (or more) efficient than iron-based blood like ours.
Evolution is all about survival of the adequate, and as long as no competing critters come along that have a radically more efficient oxygen transport molecule, these critters will be perfectly adequate.
About the only thing that having a less efficient oxygen transport molecule will do is increase the critter's blood pressure and circulatory rate above that of critters with more efficient blood, on the basis that if there's less oxygen per unit volume of blood, you only need to move more blood to the places where the oxygen is needed.  Oxygen transport becomes a slightly larger fraction of the creature's total metabolic requirement
